# 0-1 linear programming vs mixed integer linear programming problems

Tags: linear-programming

I wonder whether or not it is possible to say which one is to be preferred when it comes to complexity, since as far as I know both methods are known to be NP-complete. When you have the choice between formulating a problem as  mixed integer problem or 0-1 linear programming problem with $c$ times more variables what would you choose? If there is no proovable statement towards this question, do you know a rule of thumb that maybe at least upper bounds $c$ to when I most likely achieve better results with a mixed integer LP?

Comment: https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/3209/how-to-choose-between-high-number-of-binary-variables-or-fewer-number-of-integer/3210#3210

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Should I delete the question?